# OpenSUSE ftp server

Tags: opensuse, ftp, linux

Всем привет!

Появился вопрос: есть open suse с vsftpd сервером.При входе через хром - все хорошо, все работает, и выше родительского каталога (chroot)не влезть.

При этом если использовать FileZilla - попадая на фтп - я вижу, что смотрю в каталог /srv/ftp; Я могу извлечь список каталогов выше, могу скопировать файлы из /etc и так далее. Да, я не смогу загрузить назад измененную копию, но это все равно не правильно.

Может кто-то подсказать, как справиться с этой проблемой?

Для фтп была создана группа ftp-users и пользователь ftpadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Для фтп была создана группа ftp-users и пользователь ftpadmin

то есть все пользователи заходят на фтп от имени ftpadmin?если так то vsftpd позволяет запретить пользователю шариться где либо, кроме домашнего каталога, что то типа chroot_local_user и домашний каталог для ftpadmin назначить /srv/ftp

Comment: Да, все коннектятся под одним логином.[code]По умолчанию пользователи не могут просматривать файлы за пределами своей домашней директории. Чтобы дать им эту возможность, раскомментируйте строкуchroot_local_user=NO[/code]Это из документации. У меня она была раскомментирована, но стояло YES.Но Ваши слова натолкнули меня на мысль почитать еще) Почитал конфиг, нашел там

Comment: [code]# ######################### Local FTP user Settings# ########################## Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.local_enable=YES##chroot_list_enable=YES## (default follows)##chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list[/code]Раскомментил chroot_list_enable=YES и chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list... Создал пустой файл vsftpd.chroot_list (без этого не мог авторизоваться). Все стало как надо :)

Comment: не понимаю как поправить разметку в прошлом комментарии )все bold строки - строки, которые были закомментированы.

Comment: и еще, может Вы поможете до того, как я сам найду... как поставить юзеру ftpadmin разрешения на download, upload но запретить remove из этой папки?:)

Comment: точно не помню, но кажется это можно сделать только для анонимного пользователя, системные пользователи имеют право на удаление.